# c# - SOAP error : Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation

Tags: c#, soap, amadeus

I'm trying to run queries with some Amadeus Web Services and I'm encoutering a problem every time I'm trying to lauch a query :

> Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'name of
>   the service'.

I've read that I had to extend the size of the readerQuotas in the config file. I did it but I'm still encountering the same issue.

What is strange is that when I'm running it locally with Visual Studio 2013, there no issue. Once I'm launching it on a virtual machine (Windows server 2003 R2 using VS 2010), the error is raised.

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Did you solve this? It's my exact situation :(

Comment: Perhaps you should post your request? Might be a problem with that.